# On iPhone, How to display Animation while loading from server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to implement animation like [This link](https://dribbble.com/shots/1901531-Loading?list=searches&tag=loading&offset=1) while application interact with server.
If someone has example to implement this kind of animation then please provide me link.

Comment: There are many ways to display an animation. What have you tried?

Comment: @robmayoff, Right now I am using MBProcessHub, whenever app interact with server I show MBProcessHub.

Comment: Whats exactly what you want to know about that animation?

Comment: @KarloA.López, Thanks, I have achieved that animation using other method.

Answer (score 2):

1. Start animation
2. Server request in background thread
3. End animation in completion block of server request in the main thread

If you want that specific one I think you are going to have to make it yourself, but if you don't here are some open source alternatives.

- [DGActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/gontovnik/DGActivityIndicatorView)
- [MONActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/mownier/MONActivityIndicatorView)
- [YRActivityIndicator](https://github.com/solomidSF/YRActivityIndicator)

Comment: I know that step as rightnow I am using MBProcessHud while fetching data from server. But I want that kind of animation which is shown in link I have provided in question.

Comment: @iOSDev Then you will need to have an `UIImageView ` set its animation 
and run it until your request is complete.

To set animation on `UIImageView` of course you will need to have an Animation as a PNG sequence

Look documentation under Animating Images
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/

Answer (score 2):

interaction designer at Creativedash here =]

For something like that you'd make a png sequence, and set the `animationImages` property of a UIImageView. iOS is great at animating png sequences.

When your load starts, do `yourLoadingImage.startAnimating()` and when it's over (in the completion for your request), call `yourLoadingImage.stopAnimating()`.

There's a property called `animationDuration`, and you need to set that as well, just to indicate how long the animation loop is - this doesn't indicate how long the animation will play for. It loops until you tell it to stop.

`yourLoadingImage.animationDuration = 1 //set the loop duration to 1s`

We actually did a short blog post on this process, and it can be the same for really any custom loader. http://news.ui8.net/create-a-custom-animated-loading-indicator-with-swift/